# "Certificate required to access this resource is invalid"

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security
>   certificate required to access this resource is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got the solution. First I created a root certificate for the local domain and added it as the trusted root certificate. A certificate signing request is issued via the root SSL certificate I created in the first step. I followed  [This nice blog to resolve the problem](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec). You can check my repository where I have included instruction for the Windows system too.

Scripts to generate certificates https://github.com/sandeepp2016/local-cert-generator