# Loading jQuery CDN on Chrome gives "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Tags: jquery, spring, certificate, thymeleaf, cdn

My Team's development project uses jQuery from the following cdn. 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js

The Chrome browser is giving "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error on colsole page.

Firefox is giving "Loading failed for the  with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js”".

Edge is giving "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid"

The above error only occur on my machine. My teammates machines don't have any problem loading the jQuery. Few weeks ago I was able to load the jQuery with out any issues but recently I am seeing this issue

I tried clearing my cache/history in the browser but that didn't help. Also added "cdn_jsdeliver_net.crt" cert as a trusted cert on my windows machine, that didn't help too. At this point I am stuck, so if you know or came across this issue in the past let me know. Thanks

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate question. show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742121/how-to-resolve-the-error-certificate-required-to-access-this-resource-is-inval) for the solution

Comment: @Meziane Thanks for your response. I tried your recommendation but it didnt help. Finally I was able to load the cdn, see my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting the cdn in this case resolved the issue. For some reason my company DNS is blocking the cdn's to load. Changed the DSN server to google(8.8.8.8) and the CDN's didnot have any issue loading. Once the CDN is whitelisted, the libraries start to load fine and the issue was resolved. One thing to keep in mind is the whitelisting has be done for each cdn(ex: cdn.jsdelivr.net). Hope this answer helps some one.